# Coordinate two programs that read/write the same file?

Tags: java, php, rest

I have two separate programs that need to communicate: a PHP program and a Java daemon. The PHP program writes commands to a log file. The Java daemon reads them, executes them, and clears the log.

This works about 2/3 of the time.

I think the problem is that PHP is sometimes writing commands while the Java daemon is in the middle of reading or executing commands. That means that when it gets to the stage of clearing the commands, it erases the new commands from PHP without ever executing them.

Is there a more sound way to structure things so that I make sure that new commands from PHP don't get erased along with the old commands?

Comment: Not on file-system level and all OS'es. What one could do is to let each prpocess create a `.lock` file to signal the other process "hey, I am working on the file, do not touch it" and delete it when the process is done. Before accessing the file, each process would have to check whether a `.lock` file is present and wait until it is not.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Depends on your operating system. A mutex, semaphore, or readers-writer lock is appropriate - if you've got an OS (and language support) for cross-process synchronization objects.  https://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview

Comment: I think the optimal way is not using file system to sending commands. You may consider to send commands directly to java deamon using sockets or an http server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with log file rotation, and the patterns used there can be applied to this situation directly.

Don't truncate the file from the external process, that is almost guaranteed to lead to data loss. Instead, make PHP periodically close the file it's writing, and switch to writing to a new file.

The Java process reading the file may detect that PHP has switched to another file by listing the directory contents at regular intervals, or by [subscribing to file creation events with the `FileWatcher` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

Another option is to make the PHP process write a "hey I'm switching to this other file" message to the file, and make the Java process switch files when it reads this message.